# WEKA library M5P returns a Java exception

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, regression, weka

I am trying to use the WEKA library in Python3, since it is the language I use at work, using the python-weka-wrapper. When trying to run the classifier M5P, I get the next exception:

```
JavaException: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix
```

I have seen some posts about downloading some jar files, but I am not sure how does that solve my problem. Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: I just installed pww3 0.1.2 and built MP5 with default options on the UCI dataset *bolts* without any problems. Can you post your code for analysis? Otherwise, just use the [pww3 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-weka-wrapper).

Comment: Can you run any other Weka classifiers successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Several jars were added as is in *weka.jar* instead of getting expanded. Release 0.1.3 fixes that: https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3/releases/tag/v0.1.3